# How to combine two collections objects to one table while looping over all objects in Meteor.js?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm working on the simple Meteor Chat application. I have two different collections, textMessages and FS.images. I need to display those element based on time in one flow. Now I submit them both apart from each other and can't figure the way, while looping over them using #each handler. 
Template code :

```
<ul class="list-group">
    {{#each messages}}
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <span class="badge">x</span>
        UserN: {{text}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}  
</ul>

<ul class="list-group">
    {{#each showImages}}
      {{#unless this.isUploaded}}
        {{> FS.UploadProgressBar bootstrap=true}}
      {{/unless}}
        {{> imageItem}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Can I get some more info on how the two collections are related if at all? Are you displaying all messages for one user and each message can have an associated image?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper in the template that would combine both collections results and sort them by date if each user has set of images and text.

If each message has a set of images you can use this package for creating helper for the collection in such a way you can get the set of images for a certain message.

[meteor-collection-helpers](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers)